# Not able to change the dynamically generated button text in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I created button dynamically like in my phonegap application using jquery mobile.

```
var table = document.getElementById("skiTable");
var row = document.getElementById("skiparticulars");
var clone = table.rows[1].cloneNode(true);

var skiFile = clone.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var skiformTitle = clone.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[1];

skiFile.id = "skifile" + skiRowCount;
skiFile.value = "";
skiformTitle.id = "formTitle" + skiRowCount;

skiformTitle.value = "";
row.appendChild(clone);
skiRowCount++;
```

html code is like

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
      <input type="hidden" id="skifile1" />
      <input type="button" id="formTitle1"/>
   </td>
 <tr>
</table>
```

and here is the code for change button value:

```
$("#skifile" + k).val(results.rows.item(j).ski_file);

        $('#formTitle'+ k).val(results.rows.item(j).formTitle);
        $("#formTitle"+k).button("refresh");
tried this also 
//$("#formTitle" + k).prop('value',results.rows.item(j).formTitle).button("refresh");
```

but it never change the value.

I refered this [jquerymobile dynamically changing text for button issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094816/jquerymobile-dynamically-changing-text-for-button-issue)

and this [How to change the text of a button in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580616/jquery-change-button-text)

Comment: $("#formTitle"+k).text("refresh");

Comment: @MohammedImranN nope same like before that is test is not display in button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## jQuery Mobile 1.4 example:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8x8HE/

#### JavaScript

```
$('#formTitle1').parent().html($('#formTitle1').parent().html() + 'Button text');
```

#### Button HTML without text:

```
<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <input type="button" id="formTitle1">
</div>
```

#### Button HTML with text

```
<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <input type="button" id="formTitle1">Button text
</div>
```

Read [**this**](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/) article if you want to learn how to customize jQuery Mobile elements.

## jQuery Mobile 1.3 and below example:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/wLzA7/

#### JavaScript

```
$('#formTitle1').parent().find('span span').html('Button text');
```

#### Button HTML without text:

```
<div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" data-disabled="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
    </span>
    <input type="button" id="formTitle1" class="ui-btn-hidden" data-disabled="false"/>
</div>
```

#### Button HTML with text

```
<div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" data-disabled="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Button text</span>
    </span>
    <input type="button" id="formTitle1" class="ui-btn-hidden" data-disabled="false"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What jQuery Mobile version are you using?

Comment: OK my example was for jQM 1.4, they have completely different button layout, give me few minutes

Comment: Any idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880924/how-to-pickchoose-multiple-images-using-camera-api-at-the-same-time-in-phonega#23880924